# Find and clear a toast (Toastr)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, toastr, angular-toastr

I have a page where there may be multiple `toasts` added dynamically using the plugin https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr.

I have a `link`**(Ok)** on each toast on clicking that link I need to close only the particular `toast` not all `toast` that are visible.

```
toastr.warning("You are warned. <br/> <a id='close-toastr'> Ok </a>", {
    tapToDismiss: false
    , timeOut: 0
    , extendedTimeOut: 0
    , allowHtml: true
    , preventDuplicates: true
    , preventOpenDuplicates: true
    , newestOnTop: true
});

$('body').on('click', 'a#close-toastr', function () 
    toastr.clear();
});
```

In the above code I have used `toastr.clear()` method which clears all toasts.

Can anyone help me how to identify the `toast` of the **Ok** `link` clicked and clear only that toast?

**Update #1:**

I tried the answer given by @imjosh but, `$(this).closest('.toast')` finds the correct toast but `toastr.clear($(this).closest('.toast'));` doesn't close any toast.

If I store the toast `object` in a variable and pass as an argument to `toastr.clear()` it works. But, I don't know how to handle multiple toasts this way.

```
var toast = toastr.warning("You are warned. <br/> <a id='close-toastr'> Ok </a>", {
    tapToDismiss: false
    , timeOut: 0
    , extendedTimeOut: 0
    , allowHtml: true
    , preventDuplicates: true
    , preventOpenDuplicates: true
    , newestOnTop: true
});

$('body').on('click', 'a#close-toastr', function () 
    toastr.clear(toast);
});
```

**Update #2:**

Sorry, I am using https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr plugin not the one I mentioned above.

Thanks.

Comment: as in the `toastr.clear()` function is hinted, `clear($toastElement, clearOptions) {}` the `.clear()` function, you can pass the element to the function, you can do this with `toastr.clear($(this));`

Comment: @KevinKloet I tried `toastr.clear($(this));` but it is not clearing any toast now and no error/warning log in browser console.

Comment: For anyone using toastr.js - I am using version 2.1.1 and toastr.clear() wasn't working for me.  Adding the clearOptions "{ force: true }" fixed the problem.  Thanks @KevinKloet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer given by @imjosh works good in normal [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) plugin but not in [angular-toastr](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr) plugin.

So, I have tried to use `jquery` `remove()` method instead of `toastr.clear()` method as below and it works good.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a#close-toastr', function () {
    $(this).closest('.toast').remove();
});
```

Please comment if this way of removing `toast` produces any issue, but I haven't found any issue with this.

Finally, Thanks @imjosh for giving me the method to find the closest `toast`.

Answer (score 5):

```
toastr.options = {
    tapToDismiss: false
    , timeOut: 0
    , extendedTimeOut: 0
    , allowHtml: true
    , preventDuplicates: true
    , preventOpenDuplicates: true
    , newestOnTop: true
    , closeButton: true
    , closeHtml: '<button class="btn" style="background-color: grey; padding: 5px;">OK</button>'
}

toastr.warning("You are warned");
toastr.warning("You are warned 2");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3ojp762a/3/

Or, to do it the way you were trying, if you need that for some reason:

```
toastr.warning("You are warned. <br/> <a class='close-toastr'> Ok </a>", "", {
    tapToDismiss: false
    , timeOut: 0
    , extendedTimeOut: 0
    , allowHtml: true
    , preventDuplicates: true
    , preventOpenDuplicates: true
    , newestOnTop: true
});

toastr.warning("You are warned2. <br/> <a class='close-toastr'> Ok </a>", "", {
    tapToDismiss: false
    , timeOut: 0
    , extendedTimeOut: 0
    , allowHtml: true
    , preventDuplicates: true
    , preventOpenDuplicates: true
    , newestOnTop: true
});


$('.close-toastr').on('click', function () {
    toastr.clear($(this).closest('.toast'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/esgrwznu/

Comment: `$(this).closest('.toast')` finds the correct toast but `toastr.clear($(this).closest('.toast'));` doesn't close any toast. If I store the toast `object` in a variable and pass as an argument to `toastr.clear()` it works. But, I don't know how to handle multiple toasts this way. Please see updated question.

Comment: I am using angular version of the `toastr` plugin.

Answer (score 5):

If one wants to close the toastr from another event (not just a click)

```
$('.close-toastr').closest('.toast').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to use:

```
toastr.options.onHidden = function() {}
```

and the option was to set 'closeButton: true' and:

```
$(this).closest('.toast').find('button.toast-close-button').click();
```

This way I was able to use all benefits of 'onHidden' callback.

Not the most efficient way, but I do not have many alerts open.

$(this) is a button in the notification.